# How to check if my site is up reliable by c#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have that code:

```
static async Task Main()
    {
        await ConfigureLogger();
        var domain = ConfigJson.WebServer.Domain;
        var hc = new HttpClient();
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 10)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await hc.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head,
            new Uri(domain)));
                return;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException err)
            {
                count++;
                Log.Error($"Error to connecting {domain} №{count}");
                Log.Error(err.Message);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
        if (count >= 10)
        {
            var command = $@"cd {Pathes.pathToWorkDirectory}; ";
            command += @"killall dotnet ./WebSite/WebSite.dll; ";
            command += @"dotnet ./WebSite/WebSite.dll; ";
            ExecuteCommand(command);
        }
        Log.Information("The WebSiteController executed!");
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
```

My task is to check if my site is up by 10 times. If it is not, I run my site again.
Pay attention that I run my site if it does not response at all. The errors with code != 200 do not have any importance.
But my problem is that I can not reliable check it. Because I can get any error of type HttpRequestException(for example `The SSL connection could not be established`) and then the crontab on Linux will run site again and again.
Because that error can be permanent.

Comment: It sound like your SSL certificate might not be installed or configured.

Comment: The error can be any, but how should I know that the process of my site falled on 100 percentages? The error is when I send a request to "http://localhost:80", if I use "https://dz4all.ru", everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I refused requests to the site. Instead, I check for a process by ID. You can use that(Do not pay attention on ClassLibrary.File_Manager(). It is my own API.):

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        await ConfigureLogger();
        int procId = GetWebSiteProcessId();
        Process WebSiteProc = null;
        try
        {
            if (procId != -1) WebSiteProc = Process.GetProcessById(procId);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException err) when (err.Message.IndexOf($"{procId} is not running") > -1)
        {
            DeleteFileProcessId();
        }

        if (WebSiteProc != null)
        {
            Log.Information($"ID: {procId}");
            Log.Information("WebSite is working");
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Information("Restarting the WebSite");
            var command = $@"cd {Pathes.pathToWorkDirectory}; ";
            command += @"dotnet ./WebSite/WebSite.dll; ";
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
            await ExecuteCommand(command);
        }
    }

    private static async Task ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        using (Process proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + command + " \"";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.Start();
            var procId = proc.Id.ToString();
            await WriteProcessIdToFile(procId);
        }
    }
    private static async Task ConfigureLogger()
    {
        var logConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .MinimumLevel.Debug()
               .WriteTo.Console()
               .WriteTo.Seq(ConfigJson.Seq);
        Log.Logger = logConfig.CreateLogger();
    }

    private static async Task WriteProcessIdToFile(string id)
    {
        var fm = new ClassLibrary.File_Manager();
        var path = Path.Combine(Pathes.pathToWorkDirectory, "WebSiteProcessId.txt");
        fm.OpenFile(path, "Write", id);
    }

    private static int GetWebSiteProcessId()
    {
        var directoryFiles = new DirectoryInfo(Pathes.pathToWorkDirectory).GetFiles();
        var file = directoryFiles
        .Where(file => file.Name == "WebSiteProcessId.txt")
        .SingleOrDefault();
        if (file == null) return -1;

        var fm = new ClassLibrary.File_Manager();
        var path = Path.Combine(Pathes.pathToWorkDirectory, "WebSiteProcessId.txt");
        string idStr = fm.OpenFile(path, "Read", null).fileData;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(idStr);
        return id;
    }

    private static void DeleteFileProcessId()
    {
        var directoryFiles = new DirectoryInfo(Pathes.pathToWorkDirectory).GetFiles();
        var file = directoryFiles
        .Where(file => file.Name == "WebSiteProcessId.txt")
        .SingleOrDefault();

        if (file != null)
        {
            File.Delete(file.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```